# Angular FormGroup as Input value

Tags: angular

I have an object which is transformed in a big `FormGroup`, with nested `FormGroup`.

This object has to be spread on multiple tabs, and each tab is a different `Component` which should display (and let the user edit) a slice of that object.

I'm pondering if passing each tab's `Component` the relative nested `FormGroup` and let Angular take care of everything, or writing the `Component`(s) as dumb, which means they'll communicate via events.

Do you think a `Component` can still be considered "dumb" if it accepts a `FormGroup` as input? How would you do this?

Example of the object:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    tab1: this.formBuilder.group({
        prop1: [
            { value: model.prop1, disabled: ... },
            Validators.required
        ],
        prop2: [
            model.prop2,
            Validators.required
        ],
        prop3: [model.prop3],
        prop4: [model.prop4],
        ...
    }),
    tab2: [model.prop5],
    tab3: this.formBuilder.group({
        prop6: [model.prop6],
        prop7: [model.prop7],
        prop8: [model.prop8]
    }),
    tab4: this.formBuilder.group({
        prop10: [model.prop10],
        prop11: this.formBuilder.group({
            prop12: [model.prop12],
            prop13: this.formBuilder.array([this.buildProperties(model.prop13)])
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Inputs are passed by reference : updating the input (in this case, your form value), shoudl automatically send the edit back to the parent component. You don't need outputs for that, except maybe if you're in an `onPush` change detection strategy, to notify your parent component that it must be updated with the new value.

Comment: I think that you should rather pass around data model and edit its parts whenever and however you would like instead of form groups.

Comment: @trichetriche passing FormGroup slices is indeed easy. Angular takes care of everything and I have my model always updated. But I mean, is this how you'd do it?

Comment: @Antoniossss So what you're saying is: split the big Typescript model (the object) in multiple pieces and pass each to the relative Component. But I need the model to be always updated.

Comment: Or I could just trash the idea of having everything "dumb"

Comment: @LppEdd definitely. Why would I code more for something that is already being managed by the framework ? Outputs are great in the sense that they trigger a change detection. But if you don't need to trigger it, then don't use ouputs !

Comment: @LppEdd you dont have to split data model. It can be as large as you want. The point is to pass it as a whole and let the component decide what to do with that. Every component know which part of model it modifies and no other component has to know about this. As model is passed by reference, every change will be available to top level holder.

Comment: @trichetriche Yeah, I understand what you mean. I'll let others share their opinions, but if noone has to say something I'll go this route

Comment: @Antoniossss Sure, but the model is owned by the parent (the root) component, and it needs to be updated when a user decides to persist it. If each component has its own FormGroup, I need to handle their synchronization

Comment: I don't want to pass around more data than a component needs

Comment: I could encapsulate the FormGroup in a Typescript class, and pass that class, which has a defined interface, around. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @LppEdd *but the model is owned by the parent* that is what I am saying. Let given component do "partial edit" on part of model that is relevant to it. Root does not have to know anything about it nor editr about root.

Comment: @LppEdd you have mentioned some sort of synchronization - well you dont have to do such thing (If I think right what you might mean by that). Just provide copy of model for editing, apply changes to it and persist copy if user wants to apply changes. This is simple scenario that probably you think is far more complicated :)

Comment: @Antoniossss I would have to lose immutabily of that model however. And how do I keep each component's private FormGroup in sync with the Input model (I mean, when the user edit the form and update the FormGroup, how do I reflect the edits on the Input model?)?

Comment: I'd have to use the FormGroup valueChanges observable, but it seems overkill.